# SQL use of conditional AND on a join table to ensure at least two or multiple values are matched

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, relational-division

I have a join table named `languages_services` that basically joins the table `services` and `languages`.

I need to find a service that is able to serve both ENGLISH `(language_id=1)` and ESPANOL `(language_id=2)`.

```
table languages_services
------------------------
service_id | language_id
------------------------
 1         |  1
 1         |  2
 1         |  3
 2         |  1 
 2         |  3
```

With the data provided above, I want to test for `language_id=1 AND language_id=2` where the result would look like this

```
QUERY RESULT
------------
service_id
------------
 1
```

Obviously it doesn't return the one with service_id=2 because it doesn't service Espanol.

Any tips on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  service_id
FROM
  language_services
WHERE
     language_id = 1
  OR language_id = 2
GROUP BY
  service_id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Or...

```
WHERE
  lanaguage_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
  service_id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2
```

If you're always looking at 2 languages you could do it with joins, but the aggregate version is easier to adapt to differing numbers of language_ids.  (Add an OR, or add an item to the IN list, and change the `COUNT(*) = 2` to `COUNT(*) = 3`, etc, etc).

Be aware, however, that this scales very poorly.  And with this table structure there isn't much you can do about that.

**EDIT** Example using a join for 2 languages

```
SELECT
  lang1.service_id
FROM
  language_services   AS lang1
INNER JOIN
  language_services   AS lang2
    ON lang1.service_id = lang2.service_id
WHERE
      lang1.language_id = 1
  AND lang2.language_id = 2
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thanks.  If possible, could you also show how that works in a join table for two language, just to get an idea?  That'd be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @chadwtaylor - `JOIN` version added for exactly 2 languages

Comment: You're awesome @Dems for the quick responses!  I can now see why you said the first two examples are better in terms to aggregating multiple languages vs the join.

Comment: @Dems should that not be COUNT(DISTINCT lanaguage_id) instead of COUNT(*) in case the table allows for multiple entries of the same combination of service_id and lanaguage_id?

Comment: @MyOtherMe - If duplicates are allowed, yes.  But I'd hope that a mapping table such as this has the two fields as a primary (and so unique) key.  If I'm wrong on that assumption, then your fix is absolutely correct :)